# Switch in swift compiles but runs forever

Tags: swift, switch-statement, swift-playground

im learning swift atm and switch statements have been the toughest part so far.

the following code is suppost to simply count each vote in the array and i want it to be done by a switch (!).

my questions:

1. why does the playground run forever? (restarted it several times)
2. is the import foundation important? (that line is not my code)

im more interested in why it doesnt work and how it works, not really in the right code. im happy though for any help!

```
    import UIKit
enum SchoolMascotOption {
    case salamander, marmot, neither
}
import Foundation
let mascotVotes: [SchoolMascotOption] = [.neither, .marmot, .salamander, .neither, .marmot, .neither, .neither, .marmot, .neither, .salamander, .salamander, .marmot, .neither, .neither, .salamander, .neither, .neither, .marmot, .salamander, .neither, .neither, .neither, .marmot, .marmot, .neither, .neither, .marmot, .salamander, .neither, .marmot, .marmot, .marmot, .marmot, .neither, .salamander, .salamander, .salamander, .salamander, .salamander, .salamander, .salamander, .marmot, .neither, .salamander, .salamander, .neither, .salamander, .neither, .salamander, .salamander, .salamander, .salamander, .salamander, .salamander, .marmot, .neither, .neither, .marmot, .salamander, .neither, .neither, .salamander, .salamander, .neither, .salamander, .salamander, .salamander, .salamander, .neither, .salamander, .neither, .salamander, .marmot, .salamander, .marmot, .salamander, .salamander, .marmot, .salamander, .neither, .marmot, .marmot, .marmot, .salamander, .marmot, .salamander, .marmot, .neither, .marmot, .neither, .salamander, .marmot, .marmot, .marmot, .neither, .marmot, .marmot, .salamander, .neither, .neither, .salamander, .neither, .neither, .marmot, .neither, .salamander, .salamander, .salamander, .neither, .neither, .salamander, .salamander, .salamander, .marmot, .salamander, .salamander, .marmot, .salamander, .neither, .marmot, .marmot, .neither, .neither, .salamander, .marmot, .neither, .marmot, .salamander, .salamander, .marmot, .salamander, .neither, .salamander, .marmot, .neither, .salamander, .marmot, .marmot, .salamander, .marmot, .salamander, .marmot, .salamander, .salamander, .marmot, .marmot, .neither, .marmot, .neither, .marmot, .salamander, .salamander, .salamander, .neither, .salamander, .salamander, .neither, .marmot, .neither, .marmot, .marmot, .marmot, .marmot, .neither, .marmot, .neither, .salamander, .marmot, .salamander, .neither, .salamander, .salamander, .marmot, .neither, .marmot, .neither, .salamander, .neither, .salamander, .neither, .neither, .marmot, .salamander, .neither, .marmot, .salamander, .marmot, .neither, .salamander, .neither, .neither, .salamander, .salamander, .salamander, .neither, .salamander, .neither, .marmot, .salamander, .marmot]

var salamanderCounts = 0
var marmotCounts = 0
var neitherCounts = 0

for vote in mascotVotes {

    switch vote {
    case .salamander :
        salamanderCounts += 1
    case .marmot :
        marmotCounts += 1
    case .neither :
        neitherCounts += 1
    }
}
print(salamanderCounts)
print(marmotCounts)
print(neitherCounts)
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLGtl.png)

Thank you guys for any help!!!

Comment: τhe code, you show us works as expected, prints 70, 60, 62 on my computer :-). Import UIKit and even Foundation is not necessary here ...

Comment: thank you, ill try it! maybe my macbook ist just overwhelmed by this huge task hehe

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine running that in a playground wouldn't be lightning fast simply because of the size of your array.

`import Foundation` is redundant when you `import UIKit` since `UIKit` includes `Foundation` (although neither one is needed in this playground).

Just try to cut all of your code out of your playground, wait for the playground not to say "running" or anything like that and then paste it back in.

If that doesn't do the trick, try making the array five elements long for giggles to make sure the length isn't the problem.

Good luck!

Comment: so the code/logic itself makes sense? thank you very much!!

Comment: @felixmp no problem :)

Comment: also i have had other arrays this big and counted them with if statements, i took around 10sek max, why would a switch need soooooo much longer?

ill make the array smaller and try again